# Getting the currently selected element in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am creating a CKEditor 5 plugin for adding an id attribute to arbitary elements. I have taken a lot of inspiration from the TextAlternative plugin for Images (if you're not familiar with how it works I'd sugguest taking a look.

I am recieving the following error: `Cannot read property 'is' of null`.

As part of my UI class, I have the following:

```js
if ( !this._isInBalloon ) {
            this._balloon.add( {
                view: this._form,
                position: getBalloonPositionData( editor )
            } );
        }
```

With `getBalloonPositionData` being:

```js
/**
 * Returns the positioning options that control the geometry of the
 * {@link module:ui/panel/balloon/contextualballoon~ContextualBalloon contextual balloon} with respect
 * to the selected element in the editor content.
 *
 * @param {module:core/editor/editor~Editor} editor The editor instance.
 * @returns {module:utils/dom/position~Options}
 */
export function getBalloonPositionData( editor ) {
    const editingView = editor.editing.view;
    const defaultPositions = BalloonPanelView.defaultPositions;
    const t = editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedElement(); // ISSUE STARTS HERE

    return {
        target: editingView.domConverter.viewToDom( t ),
        positions: [
            defaultPositions.northArrowSouth,
            defaultPositions.northArrowSouthWest,
            defaultPositions.northArrowSouthEast,
            defaultPositions.southArrowNorth,
            defaultPositions.southArrowNorthWest,
            defaultPositions.southArrowNorthEast
        ]
    };
}
```

The line:
`const t = editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedElement();` is where the issue starts. This method of getting the selected element was taken from elsewhere and I've seen it used in many other plugins.

I have tested with different "elements" selected and it always gets assigned `null`.

The full code is available @ https://github.com/rhysstubbs/ckeditor5-build-classic on the branch `feature/add-id-attributes-to-elements`.

Any help would be great, TIA.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_documentselection-DocumentSelection.html#function-getSelectedElement), it says that getSelectedElement returns null if selection range contains 0 or more than 1 nodes(elements). This could be causing your issue.